# can't run npm install -g expo-cli

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I'm trying to run `npm install - g expo-cli` on a MacBook Pro but it doesn't work. I keep getting this error message.

Please help!

```
Last login: Tue Dec 10 10:58:18 on ttys000
masterminds-MacBook-Pro:~ mastermind$ npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mastermind/.npm/_logs/2019-12-10T11_02_25_659Z-debug.log
-MacBook-Pro:~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a permission problem with your global node modules in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

It's likely that you've previously done something like `sudo npm install -g ...`, which has installed packages as `root` and these packages can now only be updates or deleted by `root`. You could continue running `sudo` to install global packages, but it's a bad idea to for security reasons.

There's a quick fix for this on OSX. You just need to run the following commands:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

Comment: masterminds-MacBook-Pro:~ mastermind$ npm install - g expo-cli
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/- - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '-@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mastermind/.npm/_logs/2019-12-10T14_49_51_540Z-debug.log

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help. I tried to resolve it as recommended but i'm getting a new error.

Comment: That's because there's a space (- g) in your command! npm install - g expo-cli. Try npm install -g expo-cli

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the permissions of your  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

So you can try this command:
`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli`

Or

Follow the steps to fix it: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I tried as recommended but I'm getting a new error.

Comment: masterminds-MacBook-Pro:~ mastermind$ npm install - g expo-cli
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/- - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '-@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mastermind/.npm/_logs/2019-12-10T14_49_51_540Z-debug.log